# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField object has no attribute to_field_name

Tags: python, django, model, modelform

I'm trying to create a custom field for a ModelForm.  I'm extending from ModelMultipleChoiceField and then overriding render and render_options, however, I keep getting this exception when just trying to import my form:

`AttributeError: 'ModelMultipleChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'`

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've tried even adding a to_field_name attribute to my new class, but that doesn't help.  Here is my code:

```
class MultiSelect(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
def __init__(self, queryset, cache_choices=False, required=True,
             widget=None, label=None, initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MultiSelect, self).__init__(queryset, cache_choices, required, widget,
            label, initial, help_text, *args, **kwargs)

def render_options(self, name, choices, selected_choices):
    output = []
    i = 0
    for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
        checked_html = (option_value in selected_choices) and u' checked="checked"' or ''
        class_html = (i % 2 == 0) and u'even' or u'odd'
        output.append('<li class="{0}"><input type="checkbox" name="{1}" value="{2}"{3}/>{4}</li>'
                .format(class_html, name, escape(option_value), checked_html, escape(option_label)))
        i += 1

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
    if value is None: value = []
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
    output = [u'<ul class="multiSelect">']
    options = self.render_options(name, choices, value)
    if options:
        output.append(options)
    output.append('</ul>')
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))


class RoleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        exclude = ('user_id',)
        widgets = {
            'permissions': MultiSelect(queryset=Permission.objects.all())
        }
```

Whenever I simply do an `from myapp.forms import RoleForm`, I get the error above.

Should I be adding something to my class that I'm missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You seem to have got confused between fields and widgets. You inherit from `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which (as the name implies) is a field, not a widget. But `render` and `render_options` are methods on widgets, not fields. And you've used your class in the `widgets` dictionary.

I suspect you do mean to create a widget. You should inherit from a widget class, probably `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was...  and CheckboxSelectMultiple was what I was looking for anyway!  How did I miss that?!  Thanks.  Now to figure out how to remove that annoying help_text message.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why it's a problem based on the code you've posted, but `to_field_name` is an attribute on `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class ModelChoiceField(ChoiceField):
    ...

    def __init__(self, queryset, empty_label=u"---------", cache_choices=False,
                 required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None,
                 help_text=None, to_field_name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...            

        self.to_field_name = to_field_name
```

However, when `ModelMultipleChoiceField` subclasses `ModelChoiceField`, it's `__init__` method doesn't accept `to_field_name` as an keyword argument. It apparently relies on the `ModelChoiceField`'s default behavior of setting `self.to_field_name` the default of `None`.

Your subclass should be doing the same, so that part is confusing.