# Multi select input in admin site

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a form in Admin site that uses two fields from two different tables (Employee, Product) as input (single select & multi-select) and make it available for admin user selection and write this to another table (JobQueue).

Following is my code.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Employee Code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Employee Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    STATUS = (('New', 'New'), ('Go', 'Go'), ('Hold', 'Hold'), ('Stop', 'Stop'))

    code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=3, verbose_name='Product Code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Product Name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class JobQueue(models.Model):

    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='1001')
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='100')
```

admin.py:

```
class JobQueueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = JobQueueForm

    fieldsets = ( 
        (None,{'fields': ('emp_name', 'product_code'),}),)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(JobQueueAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

forms.py:

```
class JobQueueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Single select drop down 
    emp_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(), widget=forms.ChoiceField())
    # Multiselect checkbox
    product_code = forms.MultiValueField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        return super(JobQueueForm, self).save(commit = commit)

    class Meta:
        model = JobQueue
        fields = ('emp_name', 'product_code')
```

When I start the web-server, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'
```

Could someone please help me how do I let the user to pick the values from JobQueueForm and save the same in JobQueue table ?

Comment: Did you do something similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188617/1464874)?

Comment: Yep.. this helped me.. Thanks.